# Stateless Spring Security usage

Tags: web-services, spring-security, access-token, stateless

I need your help with stateless Spring Security. I wrote service that authorize user, my **security.xml**:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">        
    <intercept-url pattern="/auth/**" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />      
    <custom-filter ref="myFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"/>                         
</http> 

<beans:bean id="myFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
      <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>    
</beans:bean>

<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" /> 
</authentication-manager>
```

It hasn't state, thats why after my authentication, when I want get anything via another URL, it takes me 401 Unauthorized. I heard about token but I don't know how achieve this.

Comment: Why you use myfilter? Please use form-login element:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#nsa-form-login

Comment: @Michael I write a backend for Android/iOS, it's not a web browser :)

Comment: o.s.s.w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter is filter that allocated when you configure the form-login element. If you use your own filter - you should configure it.

Comment: It's not really obvious what you're asking, or what the application is intended for. If you insist on having a stateless back end, then you need to authenticate every request individually.

Comment: @Luke Taylor I know it, but don't know how to do that right

Comment: The question is still actual.

Answer (score 0):

Maximus,

This is what I did in similar scenario:

Used OAuth - http://oauth.net/

There are multiple libraries that implement OAuth specifications

```
http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749
```

Spring has an implementation that is easy to configure. There are two sample applications (server and client) from Spring for this. Tutorials are available at:

```
https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/tutorial
```

Sample working config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:oauth="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2"
    xmlns:ss="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/oauth2 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-oauth2-1.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
        ">

    <ss:http pattern="/test/customer/**" create-session="stateless"
        access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security">
        <ss:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <ss:intercept-url pattern="/test/customer/welcome*"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
        <ss:custom-filter ref="resourceServerFilter" before="PRE_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <ss:access-denied-handler ref="oauth2AccessDeniedHandler" />
    </ss:http>

    <ss:http pattern="/oauth/token" create-session="stateless"
        entry-point-ref="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager">
        <ss:intercept-url pattern="/oauth/token" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY" />
        <ss:anonymous enabled="false" />
        <ss:custom-filter ref="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
            before="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <ss:access-denied-handler ref="oauth2AccessDeniedHandler" />
    </ss:http>

    <ss:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <ss:authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
    </ss:authentication-manager>

    <oauth:resource-server id="resourceServerFilter" token-services-ref="tokenServices" />

    <bean id="myAuthenticationProvider" class="com.sachin.test.ws.user.MyUserAuthenticationProvider" />

    <bean id="oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.error.OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="myCustomerAppRealm" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="clientDetailsUserService"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientDetailsUserDetailsService">
        <constructor-arg ref="clientDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <oauth:authorization-server
        client-details-service-ref="clientDetailsService" token-services-ref="tokenServices">
        <oauth:authorization-code />
        <oauth:implicit />
        <oauth:refresh-token />
        <oauth:client-credentials />
        <oauth:password />
    </oauth:authorization-server>


    <oauth:client-details-service id="clientDetailsService">
        <oauth:client client-id="admin"
            authorized-grant-types="password,authorization_code,refresh_token,implicit,client_credentials"
            authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT" scope="read,write,trust"
            access-token-validity="60" />
    </oauth:client-details-service>

    <bean id="oauth2AccessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl" />

    <bean id="clientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.client.ClientCredentialsTokenEndpointFilter">
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="accessDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.UnanimousBased"
        xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
        <constructor-arg>
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.vote.ScopeVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter" />
                <bean class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter" />
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="tokenStore"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.InMemoryTokenStore" />

    <bean id="tokenServices"
        class="org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.token.DefaultTokenServices">
        <property name="tokenStore" ref="tokenStore" />
        <property name="supportRefreshToken" value="true" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Add this to web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You'll need to read the specs for OAuth and Spring security to understand what I did. You may extend this code to use your DB for authentication and token sharing across multiple servers.

Hope this helps.